How to get "Window" by webContent which is created WebContentsView in electron?
const { BaseWindow, WebContentsView } = require('electron')
const win = new BaseWindow({ width: 800, height: 400 })

const view1 = new WebContentsView()
win.contentView.addChildView(view1)
view1.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
view1.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400 })

const view2 = new WebContentsView()
win.contentView.addChildView(view2)
view2.webContents.loadURL('https://github.com/electron/electron')
view2.setBounds({ x: 400, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400 })

As shown above, I have added two childs.
I want to get window object like this:
ipcMain.on('xxxx',(e)=>{
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(e.sender);
  // win is equal to null
})
const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(view2.webContents)
// win is equal to null

I can not find how to get the window object by e.sender.
By the way, BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow() return null if use BaseWindow api.
